# Hardcoded /usr/bin/env in configure scripts

Tags: path, fhs, autotools

I'm building a Linux system that doesn't have a /usr directory. Getting the toolchain to work was surprisingly easy, but I'm hitting this irritation with a lot of auto* scripts: configure, etc. often seem to assume `env` is in `/usr/bin`.

A workaround is to do `ln -sv .. /usr` during the build, but obviously that's aesthetically unappealing and runs the risk of a path with `/usr` in it leaking into the final system. (There will be a network mounted `/usr` in production, and I don't want the base system to even know it exists.)

Did I install my autotools wrong, or is this just an irritating assumption configure often makes? Am I breaking FHS by not putting `env` in `/usr/bin`? (That's not a deal breaker for me; I'm already breaking it by having `/inc` and `/share`.)

Comment: as @xx4h says: you are not, strictly speaking, breaking FHS by not putting `env` in `/usr/bin`. that's not a big deal: _everyone_ breaks FHS. really. people vaguely care about it, but not really. what you _are_ breaking, though, is decades of convention. and that is much more important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find `/usr` unaesthetic, but that is the way the universe works. Almost every Unix out there has `/usr/bin/env` — as far as I know, the only extant Unix that doesn't is SCO OpenServer, and it's not a big extant. By not having `/usr/bin/env`, you aren't just violating the FHS, you're violating an extremely widespread convention. `/usr/bin/env` is a standard location, even if that standard isn't written. It is not meant to be a configurable location: `/usr/bin/env` is the one location that everybody can assume to exist.

Whether you like it or not, the solution is to arrange to have `/usr/bin/env`. Removing the `/usr` hierarchy is fine, but if you do that, make `/usr` a symbolic link to `/`.

If you're going to mount a `/usr` over the network, then:

- Make `/usr` a directory that contains a symbolic link `bin -> ../bin`.
- Make sure that on the filesystem that you mount on `/usr`, the file `bin/env` is either a symbolic link to `/bin/env` or a working `env` program.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin` is **THE** location for `env` on nearly every linux and some unixes including OpenBSD. Many scripts use this shebang to respect the in the users `PATH` set locations for `bash`, `sh`, `python`, `perl`, ...

---

Further information for

> Did I install my autotools wrong, ...

needs some more information on "the toolchain", i think.